# how to add data in bottom rows by line?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, epplus

The following code section writes on the line that I just want the incoming data in. The second bi data is not underneath it writes on top. I want to print data from firefox using selenium.
I have to print the incoming data into the excel file. how can I do it?

incoming data this (gmailtxtyaz) I want it to be updated to the bottom lines

```
sample" 
excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = (gmailtxtyaz);
excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = (gmailtxtyaz);
excelWorksheet.Cells[4, 1].Value = (gmailtxtyaz);
excelWorksheet.Cells[5, 1].Value = (gmailtxtyaz);

for loop
```

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\dd\Desktop\dene.xlsx");
               using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {


                    DateTime zaman = DateTime.Now;

                    //   var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("s");
                    ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
                    ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();

                  /*  for (int i = 2; i <= 15; i++)
                    {
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = zaman.ToString();

                    }  */

                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Gmail";
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = (gmailtxtyaz);
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Şifre";
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = (uret);
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Tarih";
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "IP";
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 4].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                    excelWorksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();


                    excelPackage.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a dictionary out of the sheet.Cells object:

```
                var _cells = worksheet.Cells;
                var dictionary = _cells
                     .GroupBy(c => new { c.Start.Row, c.Start.Column })
                       .ToDictionary(
                            rcg => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column),
                            rcg => _cells[rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column].Value).Where(a => a.Value != null);
```

get the last row with values in it.

```
                var LastRowWithValues = dictionary.Select(cell => int.Parse(cell.Key.Key.ToString())).Max();
```

and then increment LastRowWithValues in the loop to write to the next empty line.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    LastRowWithValues++;
                    worksheet.Cells[LastRowWithValues, 1].Value = "Gmail";
                    worksheet.Cells[LastRowWithValues, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                }
```

I tested the code on multi sheet excel.